# Why do some YouTube videos repeat by themselves?

Tags: youtube

Examples:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJ1dYrjuYf4
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wu3j3Qh7sTE

This happens in all my browsers (some which doesn't have any extensions installed).

Why does this happen?

Comment: appears they don't loop anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube users can loop their videos by abusing the annotation system, specifically the **pause** function. If you turn off annotations when viewing the video, you will notice that it no longer loops.